# How can I generate a class from an XSD but, keep attributes the same?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd

I am receiving XML from the database and trying to process it into my system. I have generated a class from an XSD that I received from the other team. The problem I'm having is that, right now the property names in the XSD do not match up to the property names within my application (typical). Meaning in order for me to build an object that I can use I have to create an object and piece it together with the XML. Like this:

```
DynamicEntity auth = new DynamicEntity(EntityAuthorization);
auth.Properties["DealerId] = authprm.new_dealerid[0].Value;
auth.Properties["CarId"] = authprm.new_carid[0].Value;
etc...
```

I could potentially have 40 to 100 properties to set. I've thought about applying XmlElement to the class attributes but every time I have to regenerate the class (from the XML) I will lose the XmlElements that I applied earlier. What are some suggestions?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a metadata "buddy class", by putting the [MetadataTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your class.  I would make the class that gets generated partial if it isn't already and then create another partial class and add the MetadataType Attribute to that class.  Then if you regenerate the class from the XSD and it's not partial the compiler will complain and you will remember to make it partial.

I don't really like "buddy classes" because the properties get duplicated, not really DRY, but it might be the solution you are looking for.  For a simple overview of Metadata Class, which is usually about validation attributes - but it works for any attributes, you can find on MS [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664465%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx)

You can see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26724847/1798889 for how to make the XmlSerializer know about a buddy class.

**Update**

Now that I think about this if you don't want to use the Buddy class you can build a fluent api to configure the XML Serializer.

We will keep the CustomAttributeProvider class from the [XMLSerializer with buddy class question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26724847/1798889) but instead make an XmlSerializerConfigurator class.

```
public class XmlSerializerConfigurator<T>
{
    private readonly XmlAttributeOverrides _xmlAttributeOverrides;

    public XmlSerializerConfigurator(XmlAttributeOverrides xmlAttributeOverrides)
    {
        _xmlAttributeOverrides = xmlAttributeOverrides;
    }

    public XmlSerializerConfigurator() : this(new XmlAttributeOverrides())
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds attributes to properties or fields and strongly typed
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TData"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="property"></param>
    /// <param name="xmlAttributes"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public XmlSerializerConfigurator<T> AddPropertyOrFieldAttributes<TData>(Expression<Func<T, TData>> property,
                                                    params Attribute[] xmlAttributes)
    {
        var memberName = property.GetName();
        _xmlAttributeOverrides.Add(typeof (T), memberName,
                                   new XmlAttributes(new CustomAttributeProvider(xmlAttributes)));
        return this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds class level attributes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xmlAttributes"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public XmlSerializerConfigurator<T> AddClassLevelAttributes(params Attribute[] xmlAttributes)
    {
        _xmlAttributeOverrides.Add(typeof(T), new XmlAttributes(new CustomAttributeProvider(xmlAttributes)));
        return this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an XmlSerializerConfigurator that is tied to the main one
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="K"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public XmlSerializerConfigurator<K> ChildClassConfigurator<K>()
    {
        // passes in own XmlAttributeOverrides and since object reference it will fill the same object 
        return new XmlSerializerConfigurator<K>(_xmlAttributeOverrides);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns back an XmlSerializer with this configuration
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public XmlSerializer GetSerializer()
    {
        return new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), _xmlAttributeOverrides);
    }
}
```

This class will allow you to configure what attributes are on what class/property for the Serializer and not rely on the buddy class.  We need the ChildClassAttributes for when the class has another class as it's property to allow configuring that class.

Also I use an extension method that returns back a property or field from an expression called GetName.

```
public static string GetName<TEntity, TData>(this Expression<Func<TEntity, TData>> field)
{
    var name = "";

    if (field.Body is MemberExpression)
    {
        var body = field.Body as MemberExpression;
        var ebody = body.Expression as MemberExpression;

        if (ebody != null)
        {
            name = ebody.Member.Name + ".";
        }
        name = name + body.Member.Name;
    }
    else if (field.Body is UnaryExpression)
    {
        var ubody = field.Body as UnaryExpression;
        var body = ubody.Operand as MemberExpression;
        var ebody = body.Expression as MemberExpression;

        if (ebody != null)
        {
            name = ebody.Member.Name + ".";
        }
        name = name + body.Member.Name;
    }
    else if (field.Body is ConstantExpression)
    {
        var cbody = field.Body as ConstantExpression;
        name = cbody.Value.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("{0} not supported.", field));
    }

    return name;
}
```

Now you can use/configure it this way

```
var xmlConfiguration = new XmlSerializerConfigurator<Group>();
xmlConfiguration.AddPropertyOrFieldAttributes(x => x.Employees, new XmlArrayItemAttribute(typeof (Employee)),
                                              new XmlArrayItemAttribute(typeof (Manager)));
xmlConfiguration.AddClassLevelAttributes(new XmlRootAttribute("GroupName"));
var childConfiguration = xmlConfiguration.ChildClassConfigurator<Employee>();
childConfiguration.AddPropertyOrFieldAttributes(x => x.FullName, new XmlElementAttribute("Name"));
var xmlSerializer = xmlConfiguration.GetSerializer();
```

Now all the properties and fields are strongly typed and not duplicated in a buddy class.